# Upgrading from Weblogic 10 to Weblogic 12c EJBException NoClassDefFoundError for weblogic/webservice/core/rpc/ServiceImpl

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic

I am upgrading a java application from Weblogic 10 to 12c.  One of the functions of the application uses a EJB to connect to a reporting webservice using a wsdl.
The application compiles and deploys correctly.
When the reporting service class is created, this error occurs:

> requestReply exception: EJB Exception: :
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   weblogic/webservice/core/rpc/ServiceImpl
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

Someone else had a similar issue because they did not have the weblogic jar, wlfullclient.jar on the classpath.  But I checked the server and this jar is there.

Are there other properties that I need to change due to the upgrade from Weblogic 10 to 12 for EJBs that I need to check?
The version of EJB that I am using is 3.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the 12.1.1 release, **the 8.1 WebLogic Web services run time has been
>   removed**. If you are using 8.1 WebLogic Web services, you need to
>   upgrade the 8.1 WebLogic Web service applications to Web service
>   stacks available in this release

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24497/upgrade_ws.htm#WLUPG334